# No network connections available after distribution upgrade

Tags: networking, brightness

I upgraded from `16.10` to `17.04`, and although the wireless is switched on, it tells me there are  no networks available.

Also, I can't adjust the screen brightness. Both works when using a previous kernel. Updating and upgrading there did nothing.

Thanks in advance.